# can't get the mouse move event from /dev/input/event*

Tags: linux, events, input, mouse, move

I can't get the mouse move event when using the [evtest](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/~whot/evtest/tree/evtest.c) tools to test the input events .

I just get three mouse events:

```
left click event: type = EV_KEY, code = 272 (LeftBtn), value=1/0

right click event: type = EV_KEY, code = 273 (RightBtn), value = 1/0

mouse wheel event: type = EV_REL, code = 8 (Wheel), value = -1
```

**No mouse move event**.  So where my mouse move event and how to capture it?

ps: Tested on `Ubuntu 11.04` and `Gentoo` in VirtualBox-4 with virtualBox-addition installed.

Answer (score 6):

If not on an embedded linux system I prefer to use the **input-utils** tools rather than **evtest** (and if I'm on Android I use `cat /proc/bus/input/devices` and `getevent` )

Install input-utils via:

```
$ sudo apt-get install input-utils
```

List all my input devices

```
$ sudo lsinput
/dev/input/event0
   bustype : BUS_HOST
   vendor  : 0x0
   product : 0x5
   version : 0
   name    : "Lid Switch"
..
..
   phys    : "isa0060/serio1/input0"
   bits ev : EV_SYN EV_KEY EV_ABS    
/dev/input/event12
   bustype : BUS_I8042
   vendor  : 0x2
   product : 0xa
   version : 0
   name    : "TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint"
   phys    : "synaptics-pt/serio0/input0"
   bits ev : EV_SYN EV_KEY EV_REL
```

Then I read events on my laptop's trackpoint (don't forget to move the it around after starting input-events)

```
$ sudo input-events 12
/dev/input/event12
   bustype : BUS_I8042
   vendor  : 0x2
   product : 0xa
   version : 0
   name    : "TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint"
   phys    : "synaptics-pt/serio0/input0"
   bits ev : EV_SYN EV_KEY EV_REL

waiting for events
16:43:46.516075: EV_REL REL_Y -1
16:43:46.516090: EV_SYN code=0 value=0
16:43:46.539642: EV_REL REL_X -1
16:43:46.539656: EV_REL REL_Y -1
16:43:46.539660: EV_SYN code=0 value=0
16:43:46.704385: EV_REL REL_Y -1
16:43:46.704401: EV_SYN code=0 value=0
```

Comment: The difference being what? evtest is packaged in input-utils.

Comment: When it comes down to it, I guess they do pretty much the same exact thing.  I assumed he was compiling evtest direct from the source link in his post, and I've seen people do this on embedded systems since its so self contained.  On Ubuntu 10.04  (my machine) evtest isn't included in input-utils. evtest doesn't have support for -g and -t command line options, and mostly I just like input-events more terse output format.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried actually moving the mouse rather than evtest?
I don't get anything on /dev/input/event* when I move my mouse but do on /dev/input/by-path/platform-i8042-serio-1-event-mouse. I also don't get anything when I use /dev/input/by-path/platform-i8042-serio-1-event-mouse and move the mouse across Synergy, I have to physically move the mouse.

Sach

Comment: Yes, I actually move the mouse and only get the three above events, no moving event.