# UVC Camera "Still Pin" capture in Linux C++

Tags: c++, linux, opencv, camera, directshow

I have a USB camera here that I am very familiar with and have worked with for a while. I can capture "still images" in OpenCV and with Gstreamer without problems. However one of the use cases for this camera involves a button on the camera itself to capture stills.

The camera has a "still pin" which I have wired up a button to. In Windows with DirectShow it works as you would expect. I have spent the past week in search of a way to replicate this behavior in Linux for my embedded project. So far I have not been able to find anything that I can make use of. It seems all the support for this feature is Windows only.

I have searched through the following:
V4l2 Documentation
OpenCV
Gstreamer
uvc-streamer
uvccapture
luvcview

I have also done USB sniffing on Windows which revealed a "capture begin" packet is sent. Though I have not found a way I can monitor the USB traffic from the camera during streaming. While capturing from the device, /dev/video0 is in use by V4l2 and I cannot read the bytes traveling on the bus. If there is a way I could read the raw data from the camera, I could also just handle a "still pin" button press in my application.

Any possible solutions/ideas are welcome at this point. I am out of ideas and web resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out there is a way to see a "still pin" button press in linux!

The button press shows up as an evevent. Using something such as libevdev I can use that in my code. This answer was mostly found here:

[can't get the mouse move event from /dev/input/event*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5949631/cant-get-the-mouse-move-event-from-dev-input-event)

And here is a sample output from the camera button:

```
# input-events 15
/dev/input/event15
   bustype : BUS_USB
   vendor  : 0xc45
   product : 0x62c0
   version : 256
   name    : "Celestron Digital Microscope"
   phys    : "usb-0000:00:14.0-1/button"
   bits ev : EV_SYN EV_KEY

waiting for events
08:34:01.980650: EV_KEY KEY_CAMERA (0xd4) pressed
08:34:01.980650: EV_SYN code=0 value=0
08:34:02.180637: EV_KEY KEY_CAMERA (0xd4) released
08:34:02.180637: EV_SYN code=0 value=0
08:34:02.580673: EV_KEY KEY_CAMERA (0xd4) pressed
08:34:02.580673: EV_SYN code=0 value=0
08:34:02.680676: EV_KEY KEY_CAMERA (0xd4) released
08:34:02.680676: EV_SYN code=0 value=0
08:34:03.580618: EV_KEY KEY_CAMERA (0xd4) pressed
08:34:03.580618: EV_SYN code=0 value=0
08:34:03.780657: EV_KEY KEY_CAMERA (0xd4) released
08:34:03.780657: EV_SYN code=0 value=0
08:34:04.280631: EV_KEY KEY_CAMERA (0xd4) pressed
08:34:04.280631: EV_SYN code=0 value=0
08:34:04.580679: EV_KEY KEY_CAMERA (0xd4) released
08:34:04.580679: EV_SYN code=0 value=0
08:34:05.080636: EV_KEY KEY_CAMERA (0xd4) pressed
08:34:05.080636: EV_SYN code=0 value=0
08:34:05.380704: EV_KEY KEY_CAMERA (0xd4) released
08:34:05.380704: EV_SYN code=0 value=0
```

So as you can see, button press/release is clearly visible to the system. I hope this helps anybody else in their search.

I suppose I should also mention that the button press saves a still image in guvcviewer so I know support has to be there for this type of thing.

Comment: upon further inspection of the guvcview code, they aren't actually doing anything based on the specific ev event. Using GDK they are treating that button press as a key press. So their GTK UI has to have focus in order for it to do anything which is no good for my application. Fortunately EV events fire regardless of focus so I can still use that.

Comment: Hi, This helped me a lot, thx for posting. I know this is old but... I guess the process you go through is first detect event, then capture still from stream. I have a similar situation where I cannot afford to stream because of bandwidth restrictions. Isn't there a possibility to fetch the image from the camera?